# Summing array on Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

Hi I am trying to sum an array on Javascript with the following codes.

```
var data[]: 
var total=0;
data.push[x]; // x is numbers which are produced dynamically. 
for(var i=0, n=data.length; i < n; i++) 
 { 
  total=total+data[i];
 }
alert(total)
```

for example if x values are are respectively 5,11,16,7. It shows the total value as 511167 not sum the values 5+11+16+7=39
Do you have any idea why it results like that?
Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure your `x` is actually a list of int?

Comment: Why ? Because the "+" operator interacts like a concat...

Comment: total = total + +data[i]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`parseInt()`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parseint.asp) function javascript

```
total=parseInt(total)+parseInt(data[i]);
```

Comment: You can write `total += parseInt(data[i]);`, if total is initialized as an int it will remain an int

Answer (score 1):

Try with parseInt:

```
total=total+parseInt(data[i]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply whip a [unary `+`](http://www.devcurry.com/2011/07/unary-plus-operator-in-javascript.html) before `data[i]` to convert the string values to numeric values:

```
total = total + (+data[i]);
```

Even better, use `+=` instead of `total=total+...`:

```
total += +data[i];
```

[JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/JamesD/NwKbS/).

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
var total = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < someArray.length; i++) {
    total += someArray[i] << 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use parseInt() javascript function....

total = total + parseInt(data[i]);

This looks the 'x' which you mention come dynamically has a string type. Just check the "typeof x".